# How can i put " " - space - in the seventh character?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/* Máscaras ER */
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v){
    
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"+$1 $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
    return v;
}
function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}
window.onload = function(){
    id('form-field-telefone').setAttribute('maxlength',16);
    id('form-field-telefone').onkeypress =
    function(){
        mascara( this, mtel );
    }
}
```

I have the follow result in input:
-> +11 1111111-1111

I want to put a space riht here:
-> +11 11 11111-1111

Comment: If I see that right, you want to insert a space between the region prefix code and the rest of the telephone number. In this case, take a moment to think about the fact that region prefixes may differ in length, and that each country has it's own system -- if that is to be localized, you'd need a database of all possible region prefixes, grouped by country code, and you will not be able to use a regex (except if you synthesize it from the database).

Comment: As @orithena stated, you can't follow a fixed pattern here, it differs in length and if this is a user input it can be worse.. maybe make a dropdown list with all countries codes listed..

Comment: Have looked at Google open source international phone number library https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
"+11 1111111-1111".replace(/(.{6})(.+)/, "$1 $2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just build a new string using concat and substring

```
var input = '+11 1111111-1111'
var output = input.substring(0, 6).concat(' ').concat(input.substring(6, input.length))
```